# Join operation syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to make a query through a button; though it says 
Syntax error in JOIN operation. When I click it... I can't find the syntax error, maybe you guys can help me out? This is the code:

```
   Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UnitMoreInfoQ", _
                                       "SELECT UnitsT.*, WorkOrdersQ.CustomerName, WorkOrdersQ.ClientName, WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderNumber " & _
                                       "FROM UnitsT inner join workordersQ on WorkOrdersT.WorkOrerID=WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID " & _
                                       "WHERE UnitsT.UnitID = " & txtWorkOrderID.Value)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your `JOIN` condition:

```
WorkOrdersT.WorkOrerID=WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID
```

There isn't a `WorkOrdersT` table or table alias defined in the `FROM` or other join, so your query isn't valid.

Comment: Yeah, should be `UnitsT.WorkOrderID = WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Maybe, or maybe op is missing a `JOIN`

Comment: Switched the T to a Q, and fixed WorkOrer to WorkOrder (As that is the was it's spelled elsewhere). Now it says JOIN is not supported. Also as shown in the code above I am not missing the join, it's just not capitalized.

Comment: @D347HxD So, now the join condition is `WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID=WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID`?, that will perform a cartesian product. On the other hand, if you are getting an error that `JOIN`s are not supported, then you have a different problem

Comment: I put a msgbox right before the line that is causing the error and it spits out this error after the message box comes:
`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID=WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID 1WHERE UnitsT.UnitID = '.` If I remove the msgbox and let it run I get this error:
`JOIN expression not supported.`

Comment: @D347HxD I don't really know what else can you do (did you realized that the error shows `1WHERE`?). Anyway, you are still using `WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID=WorkOrdersQ.WorkOrderID` which really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the 1WHERE which was confusing me the most. I don't understand why there is a 1 before my WHERE... woops, forgot to change the Q in the first part of that back to a T. Now it just says `Syntax Error in JOIN statement`. Same error when I use the message box before the line though (that error pops up AFTER the msg box comes up and I push okay on it)

Comment: Why do you keep changing the `Q` and the `T`?, what does that even mean?. You need to use columns from the table used either in the `FROM` or the `INNER JOIN`, there's no `WorkOrdersT` table

Comment: Oh I see the problem now... you are right; the WorkOrdersT table isn't defined but both WorkOrdersQ and UnitsT are.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easier on yourself to find and fix SQL errors.

Use a string variable to hold the SQL statement your code constructs.  You can `Debug.Print` that statement before using it with `CreateQueryDef`.  Then when troubleshooting, go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to examine the statement your code is attempting to use.  You can copy it from there and then paste it into SQL View of a new query for further testing.  And if you need help, show us the completed statement text instead of the VBA code which builds the statement.

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT u.*, w.CustomerName, w.ClientName, w.WorkOrderNumber " & _
    "FROM UnitsT As u inner join workordersQ AS w " & _
    "on u.WorkOrerID=w.WorkOrderID " & _
    "WHERE u.UnitID = " & txtWorkOrderID.Value
Debug.Print strSelect
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UnitMoreInfoQ", strSelect)
```

Alternatively, use the query designer to create the query you need from scratch.  Once you get that working, switch to SQL view, copy the statement text, and revise your VBA code to create the same statement.